# show/display/retrieve image (file path) in access to PictureBox vb net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

i'm really confused with this part. i can save 5 image with picture box, but just file path where picture is. and now i'm really confused to show 5 pictures to picture box too and print them. anyone can help me with any codes? i just need code to showing my picture to picture box but with file path and print them. please help me :( i tried with this codes but i don;t know how to retrieve pictures to picturebox

```
Private Sub search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles search.Click
  command.Connection = con
    command = New OleDbCommand("Select * from datagambar Where NoFaktur = '" & nofaktur.Text & "'")
    datareader = command.ExecuteReader
    datareader.Read()
    If datareader.HasRows Then
        PictureBox1.ImageLocation = datareader.Item("FakturInvoice") 'untuk mencari lokasi gambar pada direktori
        PictureBox2.ImageLocation = datareader.Item("SPB&BAPP")
        PictureBox3.ImageLocation = datareader.Item("PurchaseOrder")
        PictureBox4.ImageLocation = datareader.Item("TandaTerimaInvoice")
        PictureBox5.ImageLocation = datareader.Item("FakturPajak")
    Else
        MsgBox("There's No Image For NoFaktur '" & nofaktur.Text & "'")
    End If
```

Comment: What is the `datatype` of your images in database?

Comment: Datatype for image is long text, for path image @Richard Baluyut